# Google Apis C# FileDatastore

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, double-click-advertising

We are implementing a C# MVC app that gets data from Google's Double click services using the example provided here
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications.
My problem is the following.
This line of code

```
  private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                    ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                },
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
            });
```

will create a folder named "Drive.Api.Auth.Store" if doesn't already exists and will keep the authentication Tokens there as separate files.
My question is how to delete expired tokens from this folder?
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older post but maybe it helps someone else...

Normally, GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow takes care of automatically refreshing the tokens when new ones are received from the Google API. That's why you pass the FileDataStore to it and it takes care of it automatically for you.

But if you still want to explicitly delete, you can use the DeleteAsync method of the FileDataStore.